# How can catch saveAS event in powerpoint vba?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I want to disable saveAS in Microsoft PowerPoint Using VBA code.
I tried to use "PresentationBeforeSave", but I can't know when the user press saveAS Button Event from the file menu.

Comment: You cannot differentiate between `Save` and `SaveAs`, as in Excel or Word applications... You should repurpose `SaveAs` from the ribbon, or replace its action with a customized sub.

Comment: Can you please help me with the link for how to repurpose SaveAs from the ribbon of PowerPoint? @FaneDuru

Comment: Look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/bb462633(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN), please. It is an old article but it is still valid. And [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/ee815851(v=office.14)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) for a better (general) understanding...